# AutoIt Check box button click

Tags: powershell, autoit

Trying to automate away a warning window when connecting to a remote desktop.

[image: Warning window image]

MsgBox inside the If shows I have the handle.

Both the check box and connect are buttons. Instance 1 for the check box. Instance 11 for Connect.

I tried with ControlClick.

[image: my code]

Also with GUI button check

[image: GUI check code]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Or of an alternative method to doing the same thing?

Comment: Please, post **code** not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the text parameter in the first instance. Did you obtain the controls and are confident they are accurate? If so you're looking for:

```
$g_hWnd1 = WinWait("Remote Desktop Connection", "", 5) ;Wait for popup
If IsHWnd($g_hWnd1) = 1 Then ;if handle is found
   MsgBox(0, "", "First warning handle found", 5) ;notify
   Sleep(2500) ;sleep
   $g_hCheckBox = ControlGetHandle($g_hWnd1, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]") ;stores checkbox in variable
   _GUICtrlButton_SetCheck($g_hCheckBox, True) ;checks checkbox
   ControlClick($g_hWnd1, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:11]") ;selects Connect
EndIf
```